# R duplicated rows still remain after distinct

Tags: r, duplicates, distinct

I am trying to remove duplicated rows in my data frame, but either `distinct(d)` or `filter(duplicated(d))` does not remove the duplicated rows (where `d` is the data frame name with duplicated rows) -- the functions do not recognize the duplicated rows. Is there any common reason why this happens?

Below is the example dataset using `dput`.

```
structure(list(id.case = c("114746", "114746", "114746", "114746", 
"114746", "114746", "114746", "114746", "114746", "114746", "114746", 
"114746", "114746", "114746", "114746", "114746", "114746", "114746", 
"114746", "114746"), id.pair = c("78272-10794", "9330-10794", 
"9330-10794", "80739-42071", "80739-42071", "42114-10794", "42114-10794", 
"84701-42114", "84701-42114", "5533-42071", "5533-42071", "8876-5533", 
"8876-5533", "5652-42114", "5652-42114", "8920-5652", "8920-5652", 
"78272-5533", "78272-5533", "9114-78272"), e1.conditional.dyad = c(1.07224025692901, 
0.568380969299369, 0.568380969302098, 0.252545406662165, 0.252545406663273, 
-1.21808723071715, -1.21808723071797, -4.1477891182987, -4.14778911829956, 
-1.48315629665277, -1.48315629665359, -1.3047217588809, -1.30472175888309, 
-1.63547814316539, -1.63547814316453, -0.671008645771849, -0.671008645772957, 
-0.0801843233972761, -0.0801843233964519, 2.30874742062369)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to use the below code.

```
d %>% distinct
```

Comment: can you give example of rows which are duplicate in your data above?

Comment: @onyambu It turns out that there were no duplicates in the first place because of decimal points. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up front: your numbers are not exactly the same, see

```r
d[2:3,]
#   id.case    id.pair e1.conditional.dyad
# 2  114746 9330-10794            0.568381
# 3  114746 9330-10794            0.568381
diff(d[2:3,3])
# [1] 2.729039e-12
```

Computers have limitations when it comes to floating-point numbers (aka `double`, `numeric`, `float`). This is a fundamental limitation of computers in general, in how they deal with non-integer numbers. This is not specific to any one programming language. There are some add-on libraries or packages that are much better at arbitrary-precision math, but I believe most main-stream languages (this is relative/subjective, I admit) do not use these by default. Refs: [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518), [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004), and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

To continue using `distinct` without losing the actual precision of your values, try

```r
d %>%
  distinct(id.case, id.pair, ign = round(e1.conditional.dyad, 8), .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  select(-ign)
#    id.case     id.pair e1.conditional.dyad
# 1   114746 78272-10794          1.07224026
# 2   114746  9330-10794          0.56838097
# 3   114746 80739-42071          0.25254541
# 4   114746 42114-10794         -1.21808723
# 5   114746 84701-42114         -4.14778912
# 6   114746  5533-42071         -1.48315630
# 7   114746   8876-5533         -1.30472176
# 8   114746  5652-42114         -1.63547814
# 9   114746   8920-5652         -0.67100865
# 10  114746  78272-5533         -0.08018432
# 11  114746  9114-78272          2.30874742
```

where the decision to use 8 digits is arbitrary (here) and sensitive to your knowledge of the data.

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation and the solution!!!! It is perfect, even the last line of your comment (sensitive to your knowledge of the data). Great learning experience. @r2evans

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your numeric column doesn't have duplicates because of the many digits. So if you `round` that column, you can remove the duplicates if you want like this:

```
d$e1.conditional.dyad <- round(d$e1.conditional.dyad, digits = 4)
d %>% distinct()
```

Output:

```
   id.case     id.pair e1.conditional.dyad
1   114746 78272-10794              1.0722
2   114746  9330-10794              0.5684
3   114746 80739-42071              0.2525
4   114746 42114-10794             -1.2181
5   114746 84701-42114             -4.1478
6   114746  5533-42071             -1.4832
7   114746   8876-5533             -1.3047
8   114746  5652-42114             -1.6355
9   114746   8920-5652             -0.6710
10  114746  78272-5533             -0.0802
11  114746  9114-78272              2.3087
```

Comment: Similar to the previous solution, it worked well! Thank you for suggesting that I should provide the sample data (in the previous comment now removed). It helped me to find out that there was no duplicate the first time. @Quinten

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach (but I'm sure there will be better ones), the trick being that you first collapse the whole dataframe into a single  `diagnost`ic helper column, on which you then use the `duplicated` function:

```
d %>%
  mutate(diagnost = apply(d, 1, paste0, collapse = "")) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(diagnost)) %>%
  select(-diagnost)
   id.case     id.pair e1.conditional.dyad
1   114746 78272-10794          1.07224026
2   114746  9330-10794          0.56838097
3   114746 80739-42071          0.25254541
4   114746 42114-10794         -1.21808723
5   114746 84701-42114         -4.14778912
6   114746  5533-42071         -1.48315630
7   114746   8876-5533         -1.30472176
8   114746  5652-42114         -1.63547814
9   114746   8920-5652         -0.67100865
10  114746  78272-5533         -0.08018432
11  114746  9114-78272          2.30874742
```

Comment: Try this again after `options(digits=22)` ... unfortunately, it is prone to problems.

Comment: I will try this when I have time and leave a comment if it works. thank you for taking your time for this solution! @Chris Ruehlemann